# Regex Puzzle Find all Valid String Combinations

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find the possible subsets within in a string which satisfy the all given condition.

> - The first letter is a lowercase English letter.
> - Next, it contains a sequence of zero or more of the following characters:
>     lowercase English letters, digits, and colons.
> - Next, it contains a forward slash '/'.
> - Next, it contains a sequence of one or more of the following characters:
>     lowercase English letters and digits.
> - Next, it contains a backward slash '\'.
> - Next, it contains a sequence of one or more lowercase English letters.

Given some string, s, we define the following:

1. s[i..j] is a substring consisting of all the characters in the inclusive range between index i and index j.
2. Two substrings, s[i[1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%3A%5D*%29%28%2F%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29%28%5B%5C%5C%5D%29%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29&i=w%3A%2Fa%5Cbc%3A%3A%2F12%5Cxyz&o=s)..j[1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%3A%5D*%29%28%2F%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29%28%5B%5C%5C%5D%29%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29&i=w%3A%2Fa%5Cbc%3A%3A%2F12%5Cxyz&o=s)] and s[i[2]..j[2]], are said to be distinct if either i[1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%3A%5D*%29%28%2F%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29%28%5B%5C%5C%5D%29%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29&i=w%3A%2Fa%5Cbc%3A%3A%2F12%5Cxyz&o=s) ≠ i[2] or j[1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%3A%5D*%29%28%2F%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29%28%5B%5C%5C%5D%29%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29&i=w%3A%2Fa%5Cbc%3A%3A%2F12%5Cxyz&o=s) ≠ j[2].

For example, your command line is `abc:/b1c\xy.` Valid command substrings are:

```
abc:/b1c\xy
bc:/b1c\xy
c:/b1c\xy
abc:/b1c\x
bc:/b1c\x
c:/b1c\x
```

to which I solved as `^([a-z])([a-z0-9:]*)(/)([a-z0-9]+)([\\])([a-z]*)`

but this doesn't satisfy the second condition, I tried `^([a-z])([a-z0-9:]*)(/)([a-z0-9]+)([\\])([a-z]+[a-z]*)` but still for `w:/a\bc` it should be 2 subsets [`w:/a\b,w:/a\bc`] but by regex wise its 1 which is obviuos . what i am doing wrong

Regex Tool: [Check](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%3A%5D*%29%28%2F%29%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29%28%5B%5C%5C%5D%29%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29&i=w%3A%2Fa%5Cbc%3A%3A%2F12%5Cxyz&o=s)

Edit:  why w:/a\bc should yield two subsets [`w:/a\b, w:/a\bc`], cause it satisfies all 6 constraints and its distinct as '`w:/a\bc`' is super set of `w:/a\b`,

Comment: Your idea that you may get two matches starting at the same location in string is wrong.

Comment: @MaciejLos , its correct see the example 1st and 4th.

Comment: I could help if I understood what you mean by those conditions. Why should `w:/a\bc` yield `['w:/a\b','w:/a\bc']`? Why are they distinct?

Comment: @Wiktor Agreed with you there, but that's trick, differentiate the distinct cause w:/a\b, w:/a\bc  will be two different sets, not one.

Comment: Your first condition is not meet. I'd suggest to test this regex pattern: `^([a-z]){1}([a-z0-9]{0,}:/)([a-z0-9]{1,})([\\])([a-z]{1,})` BTW: i'd suggest to download and install [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), which is very handy in process of creating and testing regex patterns.

Comment: You cannot solve it with a regex alone. The question is too broad.

Comment: I think if I can count the number of char in the last group, that will solve the problem? so like ['w:/a\b','w:/a\bc'] last group will contain 2 char hence two valid substrings ,where it passes all other group matches

Comment: You would need to multiply the valid subsets in the last group with the ones in the first group. Regex is not a counting tool though, so you will have to mix it with some form of traditional programming. In a more complex case, regex wouldn't be able to help you at all here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to create a regex that helps you in separating all relevant result parts, but as far as I know, you can't create a regex that gives you all result sets with a single search.

The tricky part are the first two conditions, since there can be many possible starting points when there is a mix of letters, digits and colons.

In order to find possible starting points, I suggest the following pattern for the part before the forward slash: `(?:([a-z]+)(?:[a-z0-9:]*?))+`

This will match potentially multiple captures where every letter within the capture could be a starting point to the substring.

Whole regex: `(?:([a-z]+)(?:[a-z0-9:]*?))+/[a-z0-9]+\\([a-z]*)`

Create your results by combining all postfix sub-lengths from all captures of group 1 and all prefix sub-lengths from group 2.

Example code:

```
var testString = @"a:ab2c:/b1c\xy";

var reg = new Regex(@"(?:([a-z]+)(?:[a-z0-9:]*?))+/[a-z0-9]+\\([a-z]*)");

var matches = reg.Matches(testString);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var prefixGroup = match.Groups[1];
    var postfixGroup = match.Groups[2];

    foreach (Capture prefixCapture in prefixGroup.Captures)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < prefixCapture.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < postfixGroup.Length; j++)
            {
                var start = prefixCapture.Index + i;
                var end = postfixGroup.Index + postfixGroup.Length - j;
                Console.WriteLine(testString.Substring(start, end - start));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a:ab2c:/b1c\xy
a:ab2c:/b1c\x
ab2c:/b1c\xy
ab2c:/b1c\x
b2c:/b1c\xy
b2c:/b1c\x
c:/b1c\xy
c:/b1c\x
```

Comment: interesting way,

Answer (score 3):

You have to perform sub string operations after matching the strings.

For Example:
your string is "abc:/b1c\xy", you matched it using your regex, now it's time to get the required data.

```
int startIndex=1;
String st="abc:/b1c\xy";
regex1="[a-z0-9:]*(/)"
regex2="(/)([a-z0-9]+)([\\])";
regex3="([\\])([a-z])+";
String PrefixedString=regex1.match(st).group(0);
String CenterString=regex2.match(st).group(0);
String PostfixedString=regex3.match(st).group(0);
if(PrefixedString.contains(":"))
{  startIndex=2; }
for(int i=;i<PrefixedString.length-startIndex;i++)//ends with -startIndex because '/' is included in the string or ':' may be
{
    String temp=PrefixedString[i];
    if(i!=PrefixedString.length)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<PrefixedString.length;j++)
        {
             temp+=PrefixedString[j];
        }
    }
    print(temp+CenterString+PostfixedString);
}
for(int i=1;i<PostfixedString.length;i++)//starts with -1 because '\' is included in the string
{
    String temp=PrefixedString+CenterString+PostfixedString[i];
    if(i!=PostfixedString.length)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<PostfixedString.length;j++)
        {
             temp+=PostfixedString[j];
        }
    }
    print(temp);
}
```

I hope this will give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitive Way might not correct.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])([a-z0-9:]*)(/)([a-z0-9]+)([\\])([a-z]+)");
        var counter = 0;
        for (var c = 0; c < command.Length; c++)
        {
            var isMatched = regex.Match(string.Join(string.Empty, command.Skip(c)));
            if (isMatched.Success)
            {
                counter += isMatched.Groups.Last().Value.ToCharArray().Length;
            }
        }
        return counter;
```